# MongoDB update with matching shard key and multiple=true

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, sharding

MongoDB recommends all `update()` operations for a sharded collection that specify the `'multi:false'` option must include the shard key in the query condition so the query will hit only a specific shard cluster. If no shard key found and `'multi:false'`, it returns this error (See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/):

```
update does not contain _id or shard key for pattern
```

I am switching my code to use a sharded collection. My code is using `update()` with `'multi:true'` by default and I don't want to change that default option to avoid any potential error above. My question is if I include the shard key in an `update()` with `'multi:true'`, will mongos be smart enough to route the query to the specific cluster using the shard key and ignore `'multi: true'`?

EDIT:
Checkout these codes, which confirms what @wdberkeley said.

Version 2.4:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.4/src/mongo/s/strategy_shard.cpp#L941

Version 2.6:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.6/src/mongo/s/chunk_manager_targeter.cpp#L250

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If you have the shard key in the query, like

```
> db.myShardedCollection.update({ "shardKey" : 22, "category" : "frogs" }, { "$set" : { "category" : "amphibians" } }, { "multi" : true })
```

then mongos can use the shard key to direct the update to just the shard whose key range includes the value 22. Whether updating 1 document or 1000, all the documents affected have `shardkey = 22` so all will be found on on the shard whose range contains 22. This would also work in the case of a range query like

```
> db.myShardedCollection.update({ "shardKey" : { "$gte" : 22 }, "category" : "frogs" }, { "$set" : { "category" : "amphibians" } }, { "multi" : true })
```

except for hashed shard keys.

Comment: Thanks @wdberkeley. Could you confirm that this will work for both mongodb versions 2.6 and 2.4?